# Why am I getting just one item (instead of multiple items) in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://quotes.toscrape.com/')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {        
        'Quote': [''],        
        'Author': [''],
        'Tags': [''],
    }
)

quotes = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.quote')
for quote in quotes:
    text = quote.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.text')
    author = quote.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.author')
    
    tags = quote.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.tag')
    for tag in tags:
        quote_tag = tag

    df = df.append(
        {            
            'Quote': text.text,
            'Author': author.text,            
            'Tags': quote_tag.text,
        },        
        ignore_index = True
    )

df.to_csv('C:/Users/Jay/Downloads/Python/!Learn/practice/scraping/selenium/quotes.csv', index=False)
```

I should be getting this result:

| Quote | Author | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” | Albert Einstein | change deep-thoughts thinking world |

Instead I'm getting this:

| Quote | Author | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” | Albert Einstein | world |

I'm getting just the last item in the `Tags` column instead of all four items.

If I run:

```
quotes = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.quote')
for quote in quotes:        
    tags = quote.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.tag')
    for tag in tags:
        quote_tag = tag
        print(quote_tag.text)
```

I get:

```
change
deep-thoughts
thinking
world
etc
```

So that piece of code works.

Why isn't the `Tags` column being populated appropriately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your loop, use this code:

```py
quote_tags = []
for tag in tags:
    quote_tags.append(tag.text)

df = df.append(
    {            
        'Quote': text.text,
        'Author': author.text,            
        'Tags': ' '.join(quote_tags),
    },        
    ignore_index = True
)
```

If you notice, the only tag that's being added (`world`) happens to be the very last tag...and that's not a coincidence. It's because you loop over the tags, and for each tag, you assign that tag to the `quote_tag` variable, but you don't do anything with it, so the next loop iteration just overwrites the value set by the previous iteration. Finally, when the loop is over, `quote_tag` has the value of the last tag.

Answer (score 2):

With your code

```
for tag in tags:
    quote_tag = tag
```

you replace `quote_tag` with `tag` on each run of the for loop and thus override the previous value stored in `quote_tag`. Thus, after the last run, `quote_tag` only contains the last tag.

You need to do something like

```
quote_tag = ''
for tag in tags:
    quote_tag += ' ' + tag
```

if you want to concatenate all tags together.